# Unable to Dowloading file through href hyperlink

Tags: java, javascript, download, href

I have a pdf file called report in D:/. I am using href to download the file but I am not able to download and it says the addrees wasnt understood by Firefox. Here is my code

```
<a href="D:/Report0.pdf">Download</a>
```

Could anyone please tell where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save files inside your **development server.** Don't save the file outside the project directory. It will not works. SO maintain a directory for files inside your project directory. For example, If path seems like below,

```
yourproject/htmlfile
yourproject/Report0.pdf

then     <a href="Report0.pdf">Download</a>
```

If path seems like below,

```
yourproject/htmlfile
yourproject/files/Report0.pdf

then     <a href="files/Report0.pdf">Download</a>
```

try by giving full link.

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/blast/download/Report0.pdf">Download</a>
```

Comment: my project name is blast and it is in workspace. this blast folder contains src, Webcontent,.settings,build. I made a another folder called download where I stored the file Report0.pdf. Now when I give the path like `<a href="download/Report0.pdf">Download</a>` it gives me 404 error

Comment: will you show me the url of your html or whatever file in browser

Comment: Not pdf file link. From where you download it. That previous file link

Comment: `localhost:8080/blast/FileDownload.jsp`

Comment: send me the code i will find and say you solution. Or upload it to any site

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a reference to your local FS, use:

```
<a href="file:///D:\Report0.pdf">Load it</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference a local file and use your web page in local you should use something like:

```
<a href="file:////D:/Report0.pdf">Download</a>
```

But take notes it will not work in other environment because of SOP(Same Origin Policy)